# logging is duplicating the log messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to learn about logging. My code is logging the information that I want but it's duplicating the message.

The first code block below is at the top of my py file.

```
import logging
import traceback

# setup the file name
log_file_name = dt.date.today().strftime('%Y_%B_%d')
log_path = "C:/some_path/"

# setup the logging
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path + log_file_name + '.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

In my function I'm using the line like below to log some information.

```
logger.debug('some message')
```

My py file doesn't import any other modules which have any logging information so I'm a bit confused as to why the messages are being duplicated?

Comment: how many items are there in `print(logger.handlers)`?

Comment: Maybe the logger is getting initialized again somewhere in the code. Try running this code separately and see if it still prints the duplicate logs. For me, it doesn't. Also, check the number of logger handlers at the end of the file.

Comment: so I put a break point in at the start of my function & ran the print(logger.handlers) before the function had run anything & it had two identical handlers. This is the second time I have run my code today.

Comment: ah I think I'm being stupid. I ran the import statement more than once in the console so believe that is causing the duplication. when I close spyder down & run it only prints the message once. I think I will try building in a check to prevent this